# Apache Ant - Select All Symlinks

Tags: ant

I need a symbolic link selector in Apache Ant.

The [following selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) are available to the Core.

Can anyone advise me on writing a [`<scriptselector>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#scriptselector) for selecting only the symbolic linked files under a directory?  Or any other way?

The reason:

```
folder
|-- file-0.0.1
|-- file-0.0.2
|-- file-0.0.3
`-- file --> file-0.0.3
```

I just want to get the file that is symbolically linked by `file`.  In this case `file-0.0.3`, but the symbolic link can change and I don't want all the other files to be in the Ant `<fileset>`

Comment: Linux, but changing to Ant (from Make) because I want to build on Windows 7 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/symlink.html

I don't have a linux machine to test now but I guess that with the something like this :

```
<symlink action="record" linkfilename="my.links">
 <fileset dir="${my.folder}" includes="*"/>
</symlink>
```

You should be able to record your symlinks into a file and then processing the files as you wish. For example you could then create a list only with the "symlinked" files and iterate over it to do what you want.

EDIT :

For this solution you will need to install the ant-contrib. Just unpack the ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar to your ant/lib directory. Then use the following build.xml file :

```
<project name="test" default="build">
  <!--Needed for antcontrib-->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
  <target name="build">
  <property name="my.dir" value="/home/stefanos"/>
  <exec executable="bash" outputproperty="symlinks" dir="${my.dir}">
     <arg value="-c"/>
     <arg value="\ls -1 | xargs -l readlink"/>
  </exec>

<foreach list="${symlinks}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param="link" target="process.link"/>    

</target>

<target name="process.link">
   <!--Do whatever you want with the file targeted by the symlink-->
   <echo message="Processing link : ${link}"/>
</target>
</project>
```

The trick is the linux command which returns all the targeted files from the symlinks. Then you just iterate through them with the foreach task and you call a target in which you can do whatever you need with the files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used that and it creates a properties file with properties in for each symbolic link `file = /home/user/build/folder/file-0.0.3` but I don't know how get that back into a fileset?  What I really need is a `<fileset>` of all the symbolic links in a folder so I can iterate over them in another Ant task.  I'm not very experienced with Ant - could I read the file back into a `<fileset>`?

Comment: So I assume that you would like to iterate through all "/home/user/build/folder/file-0.0.3" right? What are you planning to call for each file? I mean which task? Exec for example or something more specific?

Comment: Do you only need the symlinks or everything?

Comment: For a given folder. Resolve all symlinks to a `<fileset>`. Perform `<exec>` task on `<fileset`>. Ignore all other files.

Comment: So for the example in the question the `<fileset>` would just contain `folder/file-0.0.3`

Comment: Check the updated answer. It is tested under Ubuntu. It should work in your case too.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll test that this evening.  The *only* reason I'm using Ant over GNU Make (which I'm very experienced with) is that I'll be able to build on any platform with Java.  Doing the above would result in the build only working on Linux.  I understand that Java detects symlinks when the canonical path is not the same as the absolute path.  I was hoping to exploit this through a `scriptdef` or something to get the `<fileset>`.  However, you have answered the question and been a great help.  Thank you.

Comment: You could use conditional target depending on the OS and do something differently when your OS is e.g. Windows. In addition even if I used the symlink task which I could it only work on *nix OSes. I am unaware of symlink functionality in Windows, unless you are using other programs e.g. Clear Case.

Comment: That's a good shout about the OS conditional target.  I assumed [Windows 7/Vista supported soft links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Windows_7_.26_Vista_symbolic_link).  Haven't tested yet.  Thanks for all your help @FailedDev!

Comment: Glad to have helped. No problem. Thanks for symlink link for Windows. I haven't worked with this yet but i am sure you can do something similar to my solution with batch :)